# Constructing an isomorphism from group of Cosets to Z

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am trying to show the below:

Let H ≤ Z × Z be the cyclic subgroup generated by the element (m, n) with m and n relatively prime. Show that the quotient (Z × Z)/H is isomorphic to Z.
The way I want to do this is define a homomorphism from the group generator for the cosets to 1 in Z, so surjectivity will come for free, and all I will have to do is show injectivity.

Is this a good way to go about doing it? How do I find the generator for the elements of the form (a+km, b+kn)?

Comment: Can you find a homomorphism $h: \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \to G$ then $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z /kern(h)$ is the quotient group and is isomorphic to $Z$ if $Z$ is the image of $h$.($G$ is some group containing $Z$) By first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Sure, a homomorphism (and a surjective one) would be mapping (1,1) to (m,n), but I am confused about the second half of your response, is this by the isomorphism theorem, because if so, I do not have that yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. I do not quite understand what you mean with "group generator for the cosets" (as the coset to $(a,b) \not\in H$, namely $(a,b) + H$, does not form a group). The most basic way to do something like that is to make you of the homomorphism theorem, by giving an epimorphism $\phi \colon \def\Z{\mathbf Z}\Z\times \Z \to \Z$ that has kernel $H$. Such a $\phi$ gives us an isomorphism 
$$ \Z = \phi(\Z^2) \cong \Z^2/\ker \phi = \Z^2/H. $$
To find $\phi$, just try to map $(m,n)$ to zero in the almost simplest way you can think of, which is not by means of the zero map.

Comment: In this case they do form a group as H is a normal subgroup (ZxZ is abelian). I need to show that the group defined by (ZxZ/H) is isomorphic to Z. I also cannot use isomorphism theorem, as we have not proved this yet.

Comment: Think you will have to make use of the order of the groups then.

Comment: The order of the two is clearly countably infinite, but I still need to construct an explicit isomorphism correct?

Comment: Well using the isomorphism theorem as axiom, you simply require a homomorphism so one such would be $m+n$. This is a homomorphism you can verify from $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$. The kernal is all pairs $(m,n)$ such that $m=-n$. The isomorphism theorems state that this subgroup is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. Though you can show that by simply mapping $(x,-x)$ to $\Bbb Z$ by taking only the $m$. Show that it is in fact a group, group homomorphism and that it is one to one and onto.

Comment: Sorry I forget the quotient group part.

Comment: so is the previous comment not valid? I think I tried that mapping and found it was not well defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31180/discussion-between-marshal-craft-and-qbert).